# How to sort a column in datagridview by time

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, datagridview

Can we sort `datagridview` column by time only `hh:mm:ss`even if this column cells contains time in `String` datatype, more information about my project, i filtered some rows from another `datagridview` to be shown in the current `datagridview` that am talking about in this question then in this cells of column contains `TimeSpan` (not 24-hour or 12-hour format) converted to `String` datatype, so i want the first row in this `datagridview` to contains the less time span of all the existing values in this column or in another way the nearest cell value from `00:00:00`, if we can sort column in this way how to do it or if we can't sort it as i planned how it works in another way.

For Example: (unsorted column)

`Column`

`00:20:30`

`00:12:50`

`00:16:00`

(sorted column)

`Column`

`00:12:50`

`00:16:00`

`00:20:30`

Thanks

Comment: sort in list, then bind to dgv

Comment: by using Linq ? @LeiYang

Comment: if you don't know how to sort, that is another question, but why do you mix sort with datagridview? then have no relationship.

Comment: cause i need from the first row that will be sorted in this datagridview to be shown in a textbox, this values are changing each time interval and i don't know another relation between textbox and the sorted cells values @LeiYang

Comment: ..you could pass the datatgridview rows to datatable while converting the `time` column format from `string` to `time`, do a datatable sort, then set `datagridview.datasource = datatable`

Comment: can i take a certain three columns including time column to datatable ? and there is a problem that cells in time column starts with two characters as "T- hh:mm:ss" how i remove this two characters @Malky.Kid

Comment: Yes, and yes. I think you have to do a bit of string cleaning as you iterate your datagridview rows to your datatable.

Comment: okay, i am going to try your idea and thanks for your helpful comment.@Malky.Kid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you comment:

> *”cause i need from the first row that will be sorted in this datagridview to be shown in a textbox, this values are changing each
>   time interval*”

I am guessing you want a text box to always display the lowest value from a particular column in a `DataGridView`. I am not sure if simply looking at a particular cell in the data grid view is the best approach. This appears to be the case and the sorting of the column you are asking for seems to imply that the top cell will always be the lowest time span.

I found that as strings the time strings sorted properly by simply clicking on the column header. As you commented, there might be other text in front of the string. If this is the case then you will have to clean up the string, otherwise the commented out code below achieves this sorting requirement you are asking by simply sorting the grid on that column when new rows are added or changes are made to an existing time span cell.

This text box should work regardless of the sorting used in the grid. The only thing this text box needs to look for is when one of the two events described above happens. If the grid has a row added or the user changes the value of a currently displayed time span, then we may need to update the text in this text box.

This is what the code below does. If new rows are added to the grid or the user makes changes to a timespan cell, then those events update the lowest time span text box. The code simply loops through the grid to determine which time span is shorter. If the data is large, it may be quicker to simply check the current lowest time span with the newly added or changed one. The code below takes the last eight characters from the string in what should be the form “hh:mm:ss” then makes time spans from those strings and compares them. Hope this helps.

Below A button click event to toggle the datagridview sorting based on column[0]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataGridViewColumn sortCol = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
  if (dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.None) {
    dataGridView1.Sort(sortCol, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
  } else {
    if (dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending) {
      dataGridView1.Sort(sortCol, ListSortDirection.Descending);
    } else {
      dataGridView1.Sort(sortCol, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
  }
}
```

Two events “CellValueChanged” and “RowsAdded” are used to update the `TextBox` `tbShortestTime`.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
    tbShortestTime.Text = GetShortestTime();
    //DataGridViewColumn sortCol = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
    //dataGridView1.Sort(sortCol, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
  }
}
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
  tbShortestTime.Text = GetShortestTime();
  //DataGridViewColumn sortCol = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
  //dataGridView1.Sort(sortCol, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}

private string GetShortestTime() {
  string lowestString = "999:23:59";
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
    DataGridViewRow curRow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    if (!curRow.IsNewRow && curRow.Cells[0].Value != null) {
      lowestString = GetLowerTimeString(lowestString, curRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
  }
  return lowestString;
}

private string GetLowerTimeString(string inTime1String, string inTime2String) {
  if (inTime1String.Length >= 8 && inTime1String.Length >= 8) {
    string time1String = inTime1String.Substring(inTime1String.Length - 8, 8);
    string time2String = inTime2String.Substring(inTime2String.Length - 8, 8);
    TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan.TryParse(time1String, out t1);
    TimeSpan.TryParse(time2String, out t2);
    if (t1 < t2)
      return time1String;
    if (t1 > t2)
      return time2String;
    return time1String;
  }
  else {
    if (inTime1String.Length > inTime2String.Length)
      return inTime2String;
    else
      return inTime1String;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, really it helped me alot. I wonder if you can help me in another question not long as this one ? and here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146778/how-to-escape-from-executing-timer-tick-the-rest-of-unwanted-lines) if you don't mind. Thanks